# how do i decrypt an encrypted text file when we are given the key to decipher it?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm still new to python and we were given the assignment of decrypting an encrypted book given to us and were asked to load the data into a dictionary. any ideas on how i can start this?

Comment: There is no general answer to this. It depends completely on the specifics of the encryption scheme (and there is no real standards around that). Whoever has encrypted it will need to tell you precisely how it was encrypted. Ideally you will want the actual code used for encryption, since people tend to wildly under-explain how they do encryption.

Comment: Note that creating custom decryptors in another language can be somewhat complicated, and often very specific to your situation. It can be difficult sometimes to get that solved on Stack Overflow (since it's basically custom software just for you rather than an answer that helps the community). If you run into trouble, I do this kind of work on a consulting basis.

Comment: Is this a purely theoretical question about the strategy or do you have already started writing the code? If the latter, please  provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And please read also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)